# Automatically log file names and line numbers with zend

Tags: php, logging, zend-framework

I'm using the following lines to create a logger via zend-log:

```
use Zend\Log\Logger;
use Zend\Log\Writer\Stream;

$logger = new Logger();
$writer = new Stream(__DIR__ . '/application.log');
$logger->addWriter($writer);
```

This works fine so far and I can write debug messages with:

```
$logger->debug('Hello World');
```

Is there a possibiility to log the file name of the script and the line of code which calls the debug function? I mean something like this:

```
$logger->debug(__FILE__, __LINE__, 'Hello World');
```

I know I can pass a second parameter (extra) to the debug function but is there a formatter or writer that logs these information automatically?